# scala - is there a way of creating a "dynamic" implicit variable? (or convert regular val into implicit?

Tags: scala

I wonder if there is a way of creating implicit value dynamically so instead of

```
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext....
```

to use something like reflection or another way of creating the "implicit val ec"
OR
convert a regular to an implicit?

Comment: This sounds like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you elaborate what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: `implicit` is compiler information. What use can it be if created at runtime?

Comment: If you want to do some non-standard tricks with implicits this should be done in compile time so it seems you may need macros rather than reflection.